# Can I get a service from container before adding a DbContext to the services?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I have an ASP.NET Core 3.1 based application. I would typically register my `DbContext` using something like this

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(scope =>
   {
       scope.UseMySql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectionString"));
   });

   // ...
}
```

However, in this case, I am trying to use [OrchardCore](https://github.com/OrchardCMS/OrchardCore) which is built on the top of the ASP.NET Core 3.1 framework. I need to use the `IDbConnectionAccessor` service to get me an instance of the `DbConnection`. So, I can register the `AppDbContext`, I want to retrieve the `IDbConnectionAccessor`.

I tried this

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(scope =>
   {
       var accessor = scope.GetRequiredService<IDbConnectionAccessor>();
       scope.UseMySql(accessor.CreateConnection());
   });

   // ...
}
```

But the line `var accessor = scope.GetRequiredService<IDbConnectionAccessor>();` is giving me the following error

> Error CS1929  'DbContextOptionsBuilder' does not contain a definition
> for 'GetRequiredService' and the best extension method overload
> 'ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider)'
> requires a receiver of type 'IServiceProvider'

How can I get an instance of `IDbConnectionAccessor` before the `AppDbContext` is registered?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`AddDbContext` comes with an [overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.entityframeworkservicecollectionextensions.adddbcontext?view=efcore-3.1#Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions_AddDbContext__1_Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_IServiceCollection_System_Action_System_IServiceProvider_Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_DbContextOptionsBuilder__Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_ServiceLifetime_Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_ServiceLifetime_) for a callback that takes both `IServiceProvider` and `DbContextOptionsBuilder`.

Here's an example that shows how to use it:

```
services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>((sp, options) =>
{
    var dbConnectionAccessor = sp.GetRequiredService<IDbConnectionAccessor>();
    options.UseMySql(dbConnectionAccessor.CreateConnection());
});
```